# How to convert SPSS file to Pandas CSV by retaining exact data?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, spss

I have an SPSS data file containing 10031 rows and 3770 columns. I need to use it in Pandas.
I used both ***pyreadstat*** and r***ead_spss*** to convert the SPSS file to Dataframe and CSV file.

It worked; all rows and columns have been imported into the data frame /CSV file. But there is a huge discrepancy in the data frame and CSV file. The values of columns in the data frame are not identical with the SPSS. So the number of rows based on column values are not equal to SPSS.

One example, the main SPSS file has a column which values are 1, 2 and -1. The number of rows for 1,2 and -1 is 7792, 2237, 2, respectively. But in the data frame, it is 7756, 2273 and 3, respectively. This happened to other columns. I cannot understand why values in the columns and rows have been changed in the data frame or CSV file. It produces the wrong output.

**The output in SPSS:**

```
Valid   Yes 1   7792
        No 2    2237
      Total    10029
Missing -1         2
Total          10031
```

**The output in Python:**

```
df, meta = pyreadstat.read_sav("mycsv.sav")
df.to_csv("newcsv.csv")

df.groupby('column1').size()
```

Out:
column1

```
1.0    7756
2.0    2272
dtype: int64
```

The output of 1.0 and 2.0 of Pandas should match with SPSS's 7792 and 2237. But Pandas has different output.

Can anyone explain it, please?

Comment: Can you reproduce the effect with a small dataset? if you can add an example of some data and the code you are using there is a much better chance for us to help you figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks. I added the code in the main question. The main SPSS file has 10031 rows and 3770 columns. I have not tried to import few columns to check if the result would be different.

Comment: do you have weighted data in SPSS, by any chance ? you might also want to take a "manual" look at your newcsv.csv file, see how many lines and columns you have there, as well as manually count the Yes and Nos.

Comment: The number of rows and columns are the same both in SPSS and CSV file. The column I am trying to see is just 1 and 2, which are unweighted. The unique values both in SPSS and CSV are 1,2, and -1. The number of -1 is 2 in SPSS but found 3 in the CSV file. I think someway values have been swapped in CSV during conversion/loading, but they should not be.

Comment: Is it possible that there's a value in some cell, somewhere, which is "throwing off" the CSV parser and causing the data for a given column to be "shifted" into another column for certain rows?  For example you might have a string that contains text that is being misread as a delimiter between fields.

Comment: @studentcoder: is that your very first column/variable in the SPSS file ?

Comment: @horace_vr. No, it is not the very first column.